# Markdown Previewer: Error- Marked is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I'm trying to build a markdown previewer using react and the marked library from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/marked

I get the error message: `Uncaught TypeError: marked is not a function.`

I don't really know how to import the Marked library. I tried to google couldn't fix it.

My html:

```
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
```

My javascript:

```
import * as React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import * as ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";
import * as marked from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/marked@4.0.18";
const useState = React.useState;

marked.setOptions({
  breaks: true,
  highlight: function (code) {
    return;
    Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages.javascript, "javascript");
  }
});

const renderer = new marked.Renderer();

const App = () => {
  const [markdown, setMarkdown] = useState("");

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setMarkdown(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <textarea
          id="editor"
          value={markdown}
          onChange={handleOnChange}
          placeholder="Enter a markdown"
        >
          {markdown}
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <div
        id="preview"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: marked(markdown, { renderer: renderer })
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Are you using npm? There's a link right on the cdnjs page to the npm library. If so, you could just run `npm install -g marked` from the command line.

Comment: Don't use `-g` flag as it will install globally. What you want to do is `npm i -s marked` inside the project directory then import it from your component.

Comment: I am using codepen. I don't know how to install it there.

Comment: @reactjs See here: https://blog.codepen.io/2020/11/18/skypack-codepen/